# My Ruby version is 1.9.3 p194. What is the meaning of p194?

Tags: ruby

I know this is a very simple question. I searched it to google but did not get answer.
thanks in advance.

Comment: The p is for "patchlevel"

Comment: thank you MichaelBerkowski :)

Comment: You should write what you wrote in the question text as a comment, or not write that at all. You should write what you wrote in the title again in the question text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the Patch Level. For more info checkout [Ruby Version Numbers Done Right?](http://blog.daniel-azuma.com/archives/16).

RVM also has instructions on installing specific patchlevels : [Patch Levels with RVM](http://rvm.io/rubies/installing)